# Why is it taking longer and longer to deploy an InfoPath template with managed code?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have InfoPath 2013 browser-enabled form templates with managed code that I'm deploying to SharePoint 2013 on-prem via Central Administration > Manage Form Templates. The more I make changes to the templates and re-deploy them, the longer it seems to take to a) upload the xsn and b) upgrade the existing template. The wait times seem to vary by template and how many updates there have been, but I've waited 10+ minutes for the entire process to complete.

The closest thing to a fix I've found so far, has been to run a PowerShell command to force admin timer jobs to execute. Since I never noticed this issue in SP 2010, there must be a configuration I'm missing. Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.